# How to edit records of two tables at the same time in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I need help: I do not know how to edit two tables of the database from the same form. I'm using `cakephp3`.

I'm trying to use ajax

Thanks for your help

Data to save in a different driver, there the script

This script is in a controller called carsController

```
 **<script type="text/javascript">**
        function editarCliente(a, b ){
        var parametros = {
                "clasificacionC" :a,
                "descripcion": b,
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros,
                url:   '<?php echo router::url(array('controller'=>'Clientes','action'=>'editarcliente',$cliente->id));?>',
                type:  'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:  function (response) {

                        $("#nomCliente").val(response.uno+"  "+response.dos);
                        $("#telCliente").val(response.tres);
                        $("#celCliente").val(response.cuatro);           
                }
        });
}
    **</script>**
```

This method is in a controller called clientesController.

```
 public function editarcliente($id = null)
        {
            $cliente = $this->Clientes->get($id, [
                'contain' => []
            ]);
            if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
                $cliente->clasifi_cliente=$_POST("clasificacionC");
                $cliente->descripcion=$_POST("descripcionC");


                if ($this->Clientes->save($cliente)) {
                    $this->Flash->desactivar(__('Cliente desactivado'));

                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The cliente could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
            }
            $this->set(compact('cliente'));
            $this->set('_serialize', ['cliente']);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any example code to show what you've tried? Generally, a MVCE is required for your question to gain any sort of traction here such that people can help you answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jose. By MVCE, we mean a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read this and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for helping, edit now. 
There the code